# angular module injection error in when running my app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started with Angular and I'm little bit confused with this error.
I don't know exactly what I've done wrong, but my console is showing this error:

> angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A179)(…)

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.min.css">
   <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    test
</body>
</html>
```

and my app.js:

```
(function() {
   'use strict';
    angular.module('app', [
        'ngRoute',
        'ngResource',
        'mainController'
    ])
   .config(['$routeProvider', function() {
       routeProvider.when("/", {templateUrl: 'www/index.html', controller:      'mainController'})
   }])

   .controller('mainController', function($scope){
      alert();
   })
 })();
```

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to inject controller as a dependency to the module

Change,

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngResource','mainController'])
```

To

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngResource'])
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vu5UvgUFaidEVfQh4Nio?p=preview)**

Comment: @vbotio Check the demo attached in the answer

Answer (score 0):

The `mainController` is not a module but a controller inside your `app` module. So injecting mainController does not make sense here. Remove the `mainController` injection from your modules dependencies array.

The other dependencies, `ngRoute` and `ngResources` are modules which your module is depending upon - for eg, `$routeProvider` is from the ngRoute module, so in order to get routeProvider, you need to inject the ngRoute module as dependency.

Comment: What is inside your controller.js file?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, do not inject the controller as a dependency. Remember: you are registering it after you create the module, and adding it to that model. Thus, it would make no sense to inject it at the time of creating the module. It doesn't exist yet. Makes sense?

Then some stuff to make life easier for you: separate out your app config stuff from your controller registrations. Have an app.js for example doing the code below. Notice I separated the steps, and I also create a config function that I then call in the app.config. This is just a bit more readable in the JavaScript mess we have to deal with.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

var config = function(routeProvider){
    routeProvider.when("/", {templateUrl: 'www/index.html', controller:      'mainController'});
};

app.config(['$routerProvider'], config); 
}) 
})();
```

Then have a mainController.js containing the controller code and the registration of it. It'll be more future-proof for when you start adding more controllers and services and so on. Also, don't use $scope, use 'this' instead, you can use that from version 1.5 I think. Only place when you need to use $scope because 'this' doesn't work there is in angular charts, just a heads up ;)

```
(function ()
{    
'use strict';

var mainController = function ($scope,)
{
    var vm = this;

    vm.variable = "value";
};

angular.module('app').controller('mainController', ['', mainController]);
})();
```

Btw don't mind the strange indentation of the code snippets, the editor on this page is messing with me a bit ;)